# How to create multiple VideoCapture Objects

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-capture, video-processing

I wanted to create multiple VideoCapture Objects for stitching video from multiple cameras to a single video mashup.

for example: I have path for three videos that I wanted to be read using Video Capture object shown below to get the frames from individual videos,so they can be used for writing.

Expected:For N number of video paths

```
   cap0=cv2.VideoCapture(path1)
   cap1=cv2.VideoCapture(path2)
   cap2=cv2.VideoCapture(path3)
   .
   . 
   capn=cv2.VideoCapture(path4)
```

similarly I also wanted to create frame objects to read frames like

```
ret,frame0=cap0.read()
ret,frame1=cap1.read()
.
.
ret,frameN=capn.read()
```

I tried using for loop on the lists where the paths are stored but every time only one path is read and frames are stored for that particular video only.I have seen in many forums it is possible to create multiple capture objects in C++ but not in python in dynamic scenario where number of videos are not known before hand.
This is my code until now

```
frames=[]
for path in videoList:
    indices=[]
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        if not ret:
           break
        indices.append(cap.get(1))
    frames.append(indices)
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't know much about python, but might it be a scope problem? So if you create the cv2.VideoCapture(pathN) locally in a loop they might get lost if you leave the loop? you should share your code to show what exactly you have done.

Comment: you only create a single videocap and loop endlessly before creating the second one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a python programmer, but probably the solution is something like:

```
frames = []
caps = []
for path in videoList:
    caps.append(cv2.VideoCapture(path))

for cap in caps:
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frames.append(frame)

# now "frames" holds your captured images.
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I edited this so that it will run and fixed some errors, hope you don't mind! The original version was only taking the first frame from each video capture device and had the frames list in the wrong place :).