# How to use OpenCV VideoCapture inside for loop?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to convert videos into frames using VideoCapture. Inside my directory 'startpath', I have multiple .mp4 files. I want to run a for loop using which all those files will convert to .png frames and will store in a separate folder for each video.

But I am not sure how to make it work for multiple files using for loop.

I am able to get the code working if there is only 1 file. Below is the code-:

```
import cv2
import os, fnmatch

startpath='C:/Users/work/Documents/data'
listOfFiles = os.listdir(startpath)

print(listOfFiles)
pattern = "*.mp4"
names = []
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        names.append(entry)
print (names) #this list has all the .mp4 files
vidcap=cv2.VideoCapture(C:/Users/work/Downloads/SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb.mp4)
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
hello = os.path.join(startpath, 'output')
output = os.mkdir(hello)
os.chdir(hello)
while success:
   cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image) 
   # save frame as JPEG file
   success,image = vidcap.read()
   print('Read a new frame: ', success)
   count += 1
```

Any help in this will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple VideoCapture Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699796/how-to-create-multiple-videocapture-objects)

Answer (score 0):

try this code .I have nt run it yet . But this should give an idea of how to solve your problem.

```
import cv2
import os, fnmatch

startpath='C:/Users/work/Documents/data'
listOfFiles = os.listdir(startpath)

print(listOfFiles)
pattern = "*.mp4"
names = []
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        names.append(entry)
print (names) #this list has all the .mp4 files
for eachnames in names:
  vidcap=cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/work/Documents/data'+ eachnames)
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  count = 0
  hello = os.path.join(startpath, eachnames.split('.')[0])
  output = os.mkdir(hello)
 # os.chdir(hello)
  count=0
  while success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, hello+'/'+image) 
    # save frame as JPEG file
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    count += 1
```

i just added a loop to go through all the file names and use that name to create a folder. This name is also used to in imwrite to save .